# How to Dynamically Autofill Cells

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to dynamically fill a column. However, with the VBA code I have now, the formula fills all the way to the max row count (1.04 million). I would like it to stop at the max rows found in the column to its left (same as manual auto fill)

```
Sub Vlookup()

Range("C2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = 
"=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],'C:\Test.xlsx'!R2C6:R1000C15,10,FALSE),"""")"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2", Range("C2").End(xlDown))

End Sub
```

I tried to use

```
Selection.Autofill Destination := 
Range("C2",Selection.Range("C2").End(xldown))
```

But that didnt seem to work either

Answer (score 1):

You always want to use `Long` when finding the last row.  Integers only go to 32,767 and there are over 1 million rows.  You should also avoid using `Select`.

```
Dim lastRow as Long
lastRow=Cells(Rows.Count,2).End(xlup).Row

Range("C2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:C" & lastRow)
```

Answer (score 0):

first you can get the last row coming from column B and use that as reference for auto fill. see my example below.

```
Dim lastRow As Integer
Range("B1").Select

Selection.End(xlDown).Select
lastRow = Selection.Row
Range("C2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:C" & lastRow)
```